# Constructing an html <math> element with js doesn't make it render properly

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mathml

The `<math>` element works as expected when written by hand, but doesn't render properly when created with js dynamically:

```js
let math = document.createElement('math');
math.setAttribute('display', 'block');

let mfrac = document.createElement('mfrac');
let ms1 = document.createElement('ms');
let ms2 = document.createElement('ms');

ms1.textContent = 'this';
ms2.textContent = 'doesn\'t';

mfrac.appendChild(ms1);
mfrac.appendChild(ms2);

math.appendChild(mfrac);

document.body.appendChild(math);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <math display="block">
        <mfrac>
            <ms>this</ms>
            <ms>works</ms>
        </mfrac>
    </math>
</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of the fraction not rendering:

[image]

Updating the existing `<math>` elements by inserting new children doesn't change their appearance at all, despite the document changing in the inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math` and its associated elements is one of the two "it's now in the HTML spec, but JS still only lets you build them as namespaced XML elements"  (the other being `svg`), so you'll need to use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) with the `http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML` namespace. It doesn't count as a "real" math element if you don't.

```js
const MathNS = `http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML`;
const createMathElement = (tag) => document.createElementNS(MathNS, tag);

const math = createMathElement(`math`);
math.setAttribute(`display`, `block`);

let mfrac = createMathElement(`mfrac`);
let ms1 = createMathElement(`ms`);
let ms2 = createMathElement(`ms`);

ms1.textContent = `this`;
ms2.textContent = `also works`;

mfrac.appendChild(ms1);
mfrac.appendChild(ms2);
math.appendChild(mfrac);

document.body.appendChild(math);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <math display="block">
        <mfrac>
            <ms>this</ms>
            <ms>works</ms>
        </mfrac>
    </math>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could, of course, also revert to using something like this: `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'<math display="block"><mfrac><ms>and this</ms><ms>works too!</ms></mfrac></math>')`

Comment: You probably want to post that as a separate answer, instead of a comment, since that's a completely different way to achieve the same result by exploiting the DOM parser's ability to tell which elements need which namespaces automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As @MikePomaxKamermans suggested, here it is as a "separate answer":

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<math display="block"><mfrac><ms>and this</ms><ms>works too!</ms></mfrac></math>`)
```

```js
const MathNS = `http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML`;
const createMathElement = (tag) => document.createElementNS(MathNS, tag);

const math = createMathElement(`math`);
math.setAttribute(`display`, `block`);

let mfrac = createMathElement(`mfrac`);
let ms1 = createMathElement(`ms`);
let ms2 = createMathElement(`ms`);

ms1.textContent = `this`;
ms2.textContent = `also works`;

mfrac.appendChild(ms1);
mfrac.appendChild(ms2);
math.appendChild(mfrac);

document.body.appendChild(math);

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<math display="block"><mfrac><ms>and this</ms><ms>works too!</ms></mfrac></math>`)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <math display="block">
        <mfrac>
            <ms>this</ms>
            <ms>works</ms>
        </mfrac>
    </math>
</body>

</html>
```

As Mike already explained, the above approach is "exploiting the DOM parser's ability to tell which elements need which namespaces automatically."